# Seeking Python library for RouteBoxer

Tags: software-recommendations

I am trying to use Azure Functions as an API that returns a set of boxes(Lat Lng for each corner) along a route, final scope is to identify if a point is located near the route based on an offset distance.

For browser, I have found out that RouteBoxer is doing a great job at this however it can not work in Azure Functions Node.JS

There is also a package leaflet-headless however it uses some dependencies that are no longer available/are deprecated.

I am left with trying on Python. Would you recommend a library that achieves this?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: For software recommendations there is the [softwarerecs.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: I'm not familiar with RouteBoxer. Are you basically asking for a mechanism that will provide the extent, or bounding box of a route? So if you have a route from Maine USA to California USA, You'd want to get a box roughly the same of the USA as your output? Further, what data do you have to start with? The route? If the route, you have the start/stop coordinates?